# Is every probability measure , on Borel sigma algbera on real line , a unique convex combination of a discrete and a continuous probability measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let us call a probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ is discrete iff there is a countable set $D \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ such that $P(D)=1$ . Let us call a probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ is continuous iff its distribution function $F$ (defined as $F(x)=P((-\infty , x])$ ) is continuous ( hence uniformly continuous ) . Is it true that given any probability measure $P$ on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ , there exist unique discrete probability measure $P_1$ , unique continuous  probability measure $P_2$ and unique $c \in [0,1]$ such that $P=cP_1+(1-c)P_2$ ?

Comment: Yes. Thoughts? (1+ year, 300+ questions.)

Comment: @Did : Sorry but I have not been able to make any progress ... I just thought whether it could happen or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong, because it was including general signed measures, and not restricting to strict (i.e. non-negative) measures.

In this case, the answer to your question is yes; for the proof of this result, please see the first and second chapter of Chung's *A Course in Probability Theory.*

Specifically, every distribution function can be written as the sum of an increasing continuous function and countably many jump discontinuities. The former part of the distribution function corresponds to your continuous measure, and the latter part of the distribution (the countably many jump discontinuities) corresponds to your discrete measure -- thus the total probability measure is a convex combination of probability measures of the kind described.

Comment: Ooh, good you came up with that answer - for I would have naively argued in the opposite direction: $F$ is non-decreasing and can only have jump discontinuities, and only countably many of those. Collecting the jump discontinuities in $P_1$ leaves us with a continuous $P_2$. - Where does this naive approach fail?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This is a good question. In fact I think you are right -- looking at section 2.2 of Chung's probability theory -- if we restrict to strict measures (and not the full generality of signed measures, which we have for Lebesgue's decomposition theorem) then distribution functions can only be continuous up to countably many jump discontinuities (see for example p.4). I will fix my answer -- thank you for pointing out this error to me.